# How to convert this multi variable integral to an integral over a single variable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to convert the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{\pi {\sigma_z}^2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^\frac{-z_1^2}{{\sigma_z}^2} e^\frac{-z_2^2}{{\sigma_z}^2} \sqrt{r^2+(z_1-z_2)^2} \ \,dz_1\,dz_2$$

to this:

$$\frac{-\sigma_z}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-r^2 t}{2{\sigma_z}^2}} \;  t^\frac{-3}{2} \;  (1+t)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \,dt$$

I have no idea how.